# PostgreSQL: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Есть четыре таблицы.
В одной - данные об изображениях как о файлах:

```
CREATE TABLE public.images (
    id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    hash character(50) NOT NULL,
    type public.image_type NOT NULL,
    uploader_type public.entity_type NOT NULL,
    uploader_id bigint NOT NULL,
    uploader_ip inet NOT NULL
);
```

В другой - альбомы пользователей:

```
CREATE TABLE public.albums (
    id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    access public.access DEFAULT 'private'::public.access NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    description text DEFAULT ''::text,
    owner_type public.entity_type NOT NULL,
    owner_id bigint NOT NULL,
    poster_image_id bigint,
    comments public.access DEFAULT 'public'::public.access NOT NULL,
    anonymous_comments_only boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL
);
```

Третья связывает первую и вторую. То есть, если images - это информация о файлах изображений, то следующая таблица указывает, в каких альбомах какие изображения имеются:

```
CREATE TABLE public.album_images (
    id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    album_id bigint NOT NULL,
    image_id bigint NOT NULL,
    sha1 character(40) NOT NULL,
    owner_type public.entity_type NOT NULL,
    owner_id bigint NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    last_comment_number bigint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    saved timestamp without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Здесь sha1 - не тот же хеш, что и hash в images. В теории, он нужен для отсева дубликатов по изображению и описанию.

И четвёртая таблица - лайки и дизлайки изображений, представленные как "рейтинги" (булево поле rating кажет, це лайк чи дизлайк):

```
CREATE TABLE public.media_ratings (
    id bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    media_type public.media_type NOT NULL,
    media_id bigint NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL,
    rating boolean NOT NULL,
    datetime timestamp without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Я делаю запрос для определения трёх самых залайканных изображений из альбомов. То есть, выбираю владельца альбома, сам альбом и информацию об изображении, группирую по album_images.id, а затем сортирую по разнице лайков и дизлайков и ограничиваю результат до трёх строк. Вот таким образом:

```
SELECT a.owner_type, a.owner_id, a.name, i.hash, i.type
FROM albums a
JOIN album_images ai ON a.id = ai.album_id
JOIN images i ON i.id = ai.image_id
JOIN media_ratings mr ON mr.media_id = ai.id
GROUP BY ai.id
ORDER BY ( COUNT(mr.rating = true) - COUNT(mr.rating = false) ) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

На что получаю ошибку: `column "a.owner_type" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.
Если добавить a.owner_type в GROUP BY, начинает по порядку ругаться на все остальные выбираемые поля, пока не сгруппирую по ним всем. Но мне нужна группировка только по изображениям в альбомах, так как боюсь, что если забью все поля в GROUP BY, требуемый результат сломается. На стаковерфлоу есть похожие вопросы, где советуют добавить DISTINCT. Добавил, не пашет. Что же делать?

Comment: Все поля, указанные в SELECT кроме участвующих в агрегатных функциях, должны быть перечислены в GROUP BY.

Comment: А результат таким образом не слипнется в одну строку? Другими словами, если я укажу все выбранные поля в GROUP BY, получу ли я то, что хочу?

Comment: Смысл GROUP BY в том чтобы сгруппировать записи по всем перечисленным в нем полям (потому они же должны быть в SELECT) и посчитать указанные агрегации. Если вы хотите просто уникальный список сочетаний указанных полей  (a.owner_type, a.owner_id, a.name, i.hash, i.type) тогда нужно просто сделать DISTINCT без GROUP BY

Comment: Я пробовал DISTINCT без GROUP BY в этом запросе, вот таким образом:

`
SELECT DISTINCT a.owner_type, a.owner_id, a.name, i.hash, i.type, ( COUNT(mr.rating = true) - COUNT(mr.rating = false) ) AS count
FROM albums a
JOIN album_images ai ON ai.album_id = a.id
JOIN images i ON i.id = ai.image_id
JOIN media_ratings mr ON mr.media_id = ai.id
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 3;
`

Сейчас ещё раз для верности попробовал, не працюе. Может, я не совсем разборчиво написал, чего я пытаюсь добиться.

Comment: Коечно не работает, вы же переместили ` ( COUNT(mr.rating = true) - COUNT(mr.rating = false) ) ` в SELECT, а это как раз агрегатные функции

Comment: Если оставить ( COUNT... ) только в ORDER BY без его перемещения в SELECT, выскакивает

ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Comment: Даайте так: укажите какие поля ъотите вывести в запросе и по каким хотите счтитать и сортировать `COUNT(mr.rating = true) - COUNT(mr.rating = false)`

Comment: Я хочу получить поля, указанные в SELECT, сгруппированные по ai.id (то есть, чтобы все оценки одной и той же картинки слились в одну строку, а в двух COUNT() из ORDER BY результаты просуммировались, и отсортировать по разнице этих самых двух COUNT.

Comment: `media_ratings` вяжется именно с `album_images`?

Comment: Да, `media_ratings.media_id` равен `album_images.id`.

Comment: Тогда см. мой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не требуется присоединять таблицу `media_ratings` т.к. из нее нужна только сводная разница количеств лайков и дизлайков:

```sql
SELECT a.owner_type, a.owner_id, a.name, i.hash, i.type
FROM albums a
JOIN album_images ai ON a.id = ai.album_id
JOIN images i ON i.id = ai.image_id
ORDER BY (
  SELECT COUNT(mr.rating) filter (where mr.rating = true) 
       - COUNT(mr.rating) filter (where mr.rating = true)
  from media_ratings mr where mr.media_id = ai.id
) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ещё решение от себя. Вместо выборки в ORDER BY присоединяем к основной таблице вместо media_requests полученный от внутреннего запроса список айдишников изображений, уже упорядоченный, как нам нужно, а затем ещё раз указываем сортировку снаружи. Вот таким образом:

```
SELECT a.owner_type, a.owner_id, a.name, i.hash, i.type
FROM albums a
JOIN album_images ai ON ai.album_id = a.id
JOIN images i ON i.id = ai.image_id
JOIN (
    SELECT ai.id, ( COUNT(mr.rating = true) - COUNT(mr.rating = false) ) AS diff
    FROM album_images ai
    JOIN media_ratings mr ON mr.media_id = ai.id
    WHERE mr.media_type = 'image'
    GROUP BY ai.id
    ORDER BY diff DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t ON t.id = ai.id
ORDER BY t.diff DESC;
```

Такой метод наверняка работает медленнее, но его плюс в том, что при пустой таблице media_requests полученный результат тоже будет пустым, пустые места рейтинга в нём не заполнятся случайными строками из album_images.